# How to add all the data and py file to pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I have a project, which I obfuscated by python pyarmor.
I want to make it as a package. I follow the documentation, How To Pack Obfuscated Scripts, 
But it's showing me an error.
SO I just want to know how do I provide pyinstaller to my all module, file, data, and directory to make a .exe file.

To obfuscate my project i used :
pyarmor build

TO pack my obfuscated project :
pyinstaller --onefile run.py

run.py is the main entry file.

Comment: Please let us know what commands you are using and which error exacly it shows.

Comment: Not able to add .so file